# open two csv file in ruby and copy some of the columns from both files into third file

Tags: ruby

Open two csv files.The field name and values label, sample are the same in both files, combine the average_old and average_new to to third csv.
I could find some of the results indicating faster csv but it's totally new to me. Any small snippet is appreciated.If the row exists in only one file I want to keep it in the new file.

For example:

File1.csv

```
label,sample,average_old
t1,10,12
t2,11,13
```

File2.csv

```
label,sample,average_new
t1,10,16
t2,11,15
```

File3.csv should be

```
label,sample,average_old,average_new
t1,10,12,16
t2,11,13,15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('/tmp/File2.csv').inject(
  CSV.foreach('/tmp/File1.csv').inject({}) do |memo, row| 
    (memo[row.first] ||= []) << row
    memo
  end
) do |memo, row| 
  (memo[row.first] ||= []) << row
  memo
end.map(&:flatten).map(&:uniq)

#⇒ [
#    ["label", "sample", "average_old", "average_new"], 
#    ["t1", "10", "12", "16"], 
#    ["t2", "11", "13", "15"]
#  ]
```

Writing this array to file [should be easy](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Writing).